# Updating Record If Exsit and not A Blank Field

Tags: c#, ms-access, record

I'm New in Windows Application Programming With C#
I Had A project that connect Windows Application With Microsoft Access Database , I Want to create a button that update records if only Not A blank Box , Any one have an example ??
Regards

Comment: You could google an example?

Comment: I did Already , But Nothing , Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the solition by identify memorystream

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer :
    select Date from Access Data Base , With not null filter then update it 
Long Answer :
get all data in Your Access Database in this Table And Add [This Will Help You](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128361/getting-data-from-ms-access-database-and-display-it-in-a-listbox)

then select by linq query
then update

or you can use EF

i hope help you

Comment: Thanks Kerollos for Help but that's not what i want .