# Pulling in Access Database Entry using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm trying to figure out how to pull specific Entry lines from an Access Database and into a C# Program.

I'm working with a friend to make a sudoku game. We want to pull different levels of difficulty of puzzles from an access database and into a C# program.

Now my question is: Is there a way to have to program pull the specific lines from the database or would we need to load them all into the program and then have them selected from there? These would be put into a two-dimensional array.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: What did you try so far? What does your database look like?

Comment: Here's one [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128361/getting-data-from-ms-access-database-and-display-it-in-a-listbox) that might help you on your way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what soduku is, but I'm thinking that you need to query your Access DB.  Something like this should get you started.

```
Class BusLogic
{
 public List<string> ListboxItems = new List<string>();
 public void PopulateListBoxItems(string userName)
 {
  string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\redgabanan\Desktop\Gabanan_Red_dbaseCon\Red_Database.accdb";
  using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
  {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader reader = null;
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * from  Users WHERE LastName='@1'", connection);            
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", userName)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();    
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ListboxItems.Add(reader[1].ToString()+","+reader[2].ToString());
        }    
   }
 }    
}
```

You could use a DataReader as well.

http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_data_reader.html

You definitely don't want to pull in all data from a Table; you need to somehow Query the data set.